# Absolutely positioning not working as expected

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement a grid like layout of images with their corresponding title absolutely positioned relative to that image.

usually when the parent is positioned relatively, the child position absolute works perfectly. Not in this case :(( No matter what I've tried I cannot get this to work.

Sorry had to delete the code as images no longer available.

Michaels solution worked.

Comment: CodePen is useful, but code in questions is amazing!

Comment: add a fiddle and I will help you...

Comment: whats the issue with this codepen?i opened and found nothing wrong

Comment: Absolute positioning will not be working, because nowhere in your CSS does it say `position: absolute;` ;)

Comment: .heroes h3 has position:absolute applied to it

Comment: Only a couple of the titles are showing and they are not being positioned relative to their container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.hero div` has an effective height of 0. Give this element a height and your absolute positioning will work as expected.